# Glitch on one type death (but not the other) and winning in java applet game

Tags: java, audio, applet, paint

This is a java Applet game. There are 3 game states, Running, Dead and Win. My question is two part, but I think they are related since they happen at the same point.

Question 1: When you die by losing all your health the "Start over" button is displayed once. When you die by falling in a hole, it fills the screen over and over. It also fills the screen when you "win" the level.

Question 2: Same criteria as question 1, only this time about sound. Death by enemy plays the "death" song. Death by hole causes the song to glitch over and over on the first note, as though it is caught in a loop. Winning makes the win song glitch the same way.

```
package androidGame;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.net.*;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

import androidGame.framework.Animation;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.net.URL;

public class StartingClass extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener,
        ActionListener {

    enum GameState {
        Running, Dead, Win
    }

    GameState state = GameState.Running;

    private static Robot robot;
    public static Heliboy hb, hb2, hb3, hb4, hb5, hb6, hb7, hb8, hb9, hb10,
            hb11, hb12, hb13, hb14, hb15, hb16;
    public static int score = 0;
    public static int rHealth = 120;
    private Font font = new Font(null, Font.BOLD, 30);

    private Image image, currentSprite, character, character2, character3,
            characterDown, characterJumped, background, heliboy, heliboy2,
            heliboy3, heliboy4, heliboy5;

    public static Image tilegrassTop, tilegrassBot, tilegrassLeft,
            tilegrassRight, tiledirt, tilefire, tiledoor;

    private Graphics second;
    private URL base;
    private static Background bg1, bg2;
    private Animation anim, hanim;
    int level = 1;
    Button next, sOver;

    private ArrayList<Tile> tilearray = new ArrayList<Tile>();

    @Override
    public void init() {

        setSize(800, 480);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(this);
        Frame frame = (Frame) this.getParent().getParent();
        frame.setTitle("Robot Mania");
        try {
            base = getDocumentBase();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        // Image Setups
        character = getImage(base, "data/character.png");
        character2 = getImage(base, "data/character2.png");
        character3 = getImage(base, "data/character3.png");

        characterDown = getImage(base, "data/down.png");
        characterJumped = getImage(base, "data/jumped.png");

        heliboy = getImage(base, "data/heliboy.png");
        heliboy2 = getImage(base, "data/heliboy2.png");
        heliboy3 = getImage(base, "data/heliboy3.png");
        heliboy4 = getImage(base, "data/heliboy4.png");
        heliboy5 = getImage(base, "data/heliboy5.png");

        background = getImage(base, "data/trees.png");

        tiledirt = getImage(base, "data/tiledirt.png");
        tilegrassTop = getImage(base, "data/tilegrasstop.png");
        tilegrassBot = getImage(base, "data/tilegrassbot.png");
        tilegrassLeft = getImage(base, "data/tilegrassleft.png");
        tilegrassRight = getImage(base, "data/tilegrassright.png");
        tilefire = getImage(base, "data/tilefire.png");
        tiledoor = getImage(base, "data/tiledoor.png");

        anim = new Animation();
        anim.addFrame(character, 1250);
        anim.addFrame(character2, 50);
        anim.addFrame(character3, 50);
        anim.addFrame(character2, 50);

        hanim = new Animation();
        hanim.addFrame(heliboy, 100);
        hanim.addFrame(heliboy2, 100);
        hanim.addFrame(heliboy3, 100);
        hanim.addFrame(heliboy4, 100);
        hanim.addFrame(heliboy5, 100);
        hanim.addFrame(heliboy4, 100);
        hanim.addFrame(heliboy3, 100);
        hanim.addFrame(heliboy2, 100);

        currentSprite = anim.getImage();
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        // Sound.MAIN.loop();
        bg1 = new Background(0, 0);
        bg2 = new Background(2160, 0);
        robot = new Robot();
        // Initialize Tiles
        try {
            loadMap("data/map" + level + ".txt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Random random = new Random();
        int randomInt = random.nextInt(500);

        hb = new Heliboy(700, 360);
        hb2 = new Heliboy(900 + randomInt, 360);
        hb3 = new Heliboy(2300 + randomInt, 360);
        hb4 = new Heliboy(2900 + randomInt, 360);
        hb5 = new Heliboy(3400 + randomInt, 360);
        hb6 = new Heliboy(3900 + randomInt, 360);
        hb7 = new Heliboy(4300 + randomInt, 360);
        hb8 = new Heliboy(4700 + randomInt, 360);
        hb9 = new Heliboy(5000 + randomInt, 360);
        hb10 = new Heliboy(5300 + randomInt, 360);
        hb11 = new Heliboy(5700 + randomInt, 360);
        hb12 = new Heliboy(6000 + randomInt, 360);
        hb13 = new Heliboy(6300 + randomInt, 360);
        hb14 = new Heliboy(6700 + randomInt, 360);
        hb15 = new Heliboy(7000 + randomInt, 360);
        hb16 = new Heliboy(7200 + randomInt, 360);

        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    private void loadMap(String filename) throws IOException {
        ArrayList lines = new ArrayList();
        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        while (true) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            // no more lines to read
            if (line == null) {
                reader.close();
                break;
            }

            if (!line.startsWith("!")) {
                lines.add(line);
                width = Math.max(width, line.length());

            }
        }
        height = lines.size();

        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
            String line = (String) lines.get(j);
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {

                if (i < line.length()) {
                    char ch = line.charAt(i);
                    Tile t = new Tile(i, j, Character.getNumericValue(ch));
                    tilearray.add(t);
                }

            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (state == GameState.Running) {

            while (true) {

                robot.update();
                if (robot.isJumped()) {
                    currentSprite = characterJumped;
                } else if (robot.isJumped() == false
                        && robot.isDucked() == false) {

                    currentSprite = anim.getImage();
                }

                ArrayList projectiles = robot.getProjectiles();
                for (int i = 0; i < projectiles.size(); i++) {
                    Projectile p = (Projectile) projectiles.get(i);
                    if (p.isVisible() == true) {
                        p.update();

                    } else {
                        projectiles.remove(i);
                    }
                }

                updateTiles();
                hb.update();
                hb2.update();
                hb3.update();
                hb4.update();
                hb5.update();
                hb6.update();
                hb7.update();
                hb8.update();
                hb9.update();
                hb10.update();
                hb11.update();
                hb12.update();
                hb13.update();
                hb14.update();
                hb15.update();
                hb16.update();
                bg1.update();
                bg2.update();
                animate();
                repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(17);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (rHealth == 0) {
                    state = GameState.Dead;
                    Sound.MAIN.stop();
                    // Sound.DIE.play();

                    sOver = new Button("Start Over");
                    this.add(sOver);
                    sOver.addActionListener(this);
                    sOver.setVisible(true);
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
                }
                if (robot.getCenterY() > 500) {
                    state = GameState.Dead;
                    Sound.MAIN.stop();
                    // Sound.DIE.play();

                    sOver = new Button("Start Over");
                    this.add(sOver);
                    sOver.addActionListener(this);
                    sOver.setVisible(true);
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();

                }

                if (score == 35) {
                    state = GameState.Win;
                    Sound.MAIN.stop();
                    // Sound.WIN.play();

                    next = new Button("Next Level");
                    this.add(next);
                    next.addActionListener(this);
                    next.setVisible(true);
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void animate() {
        anim.update(10);
        hanim.update(50);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        if (image == null) {
            image = createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            second = image.getGraphics();
        }

        second.setColor(getBackground());
        second.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        second.setColor(getForeground());
        paint(second);

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        if (state == GameState.Running) {

            g.drawImage(background, bg1.getBgX(), bg1.getBgY(), this);
            g.drawImage(background, bg2.getBgX(), bg2.getBgY(), this);
            paintTiles(g);

            ArrayList projectiles = robot.getProjectiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < projectiles.size(); i++) {
                Projectile p = (Projectile) projectiles.get(i);
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g.fillRect(p.getX(), p.getY(), 10, 5);
            }

            g.drawImage(currentSprite, robot.getCenterX() - 61,
                    robot.getCenterY() - 63, this);
            g.drawImage(hanim.getImage(), hb.getCenterX() - 48,
                    hb.getCenterY() - 48, this);
            g.drawImage(hanim.getImage(), hb2.getCenterX() - 48,
                    hb2.getCenterY() - 48, this);
            g.drawImage(hanim.getImage(), hb3.getCenterX() - 48,
                    hb3.getCenterY() - 48, this);
            g.drawImage(hanim.getImage(), hb4.getCenterX() - 48,
                    hb4.getCenterY() - 48, this);
            g.drawImage(hanim.getImage(), hb5.getCenterX() - 48,
                    hb5.getCenterY() - 48, this);
            g.drawImage(hanim.getImage(), hb6.getCenterX() - 48,
                    hb6.getCenterY() - 48, this);
            g.drawImage(hanim.getImage(), hb7.getCenterX() - 48,
                    hb7.getCenterY() - 48, this);
            g.drawImage(hanim.getImage(), hb8.getCenterX() - 48,
                    hb8.getCenterY() - 48, this);
            g.drawImage(hanim.getImage(), hb9.getCenterX() - 48,
                    hb9.getCenterY() - 48, this);
            g.drawImage(hanim.getImage(), hb10.getCenterX() - 48,
                    hb10.getCenterY() - 48, this);
            g.drawImage(hanim.getImage(), hb11.getCenterX() - 48,
                    hb11.getCenterY() - 48, this);
            g.drawImage(hanim.getImage(), hb12.getCenterX() - 48,
                    hb12.getCenterY() - 48, this);
            g.drawImage(hanim.getImage(), hb13.getCenterX() - 48,
                    hb13.getCenterY() - 48, this);
            g.drawImage(hanim.getImage(), hb14.getCenterX() - 48,
                    hb14.getCenterY() - 48, this);
            g.drawImage(hanim.getImage(), hb15.getCenterX() - 48,
                    hb15.getCenterY() - 48, this);
            g.drawImage(hanim.getImage(), hb16.getCenterX() - 48,
                    hb16.getCenterY() - 48, this);

            g.setFont(font);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.drawString("Health: " + Integer.toString(rHealth), 5, 30);
            g.drawString("Score: " + Integer.toString(score), 650, 30);

        } else if (state == GameState.Dead) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 480);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.drawString("You're Dead!", 300, 200);
            g.drawString("Score: " + score, 300, 250);

        } else if (state == GameState.Win) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 480);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.drawString("You Beat this level!", 300, 200);
            g.drawString("Score: " + score, 300, 250);
        }
    }

    private void updateTiles() {

        for (int i = 0; i < tilearray.size(); i++) {
            Tile t = (Tile) tilearray.get(i);
            t.update();
        }

    }

    private void paintTiles(Graphics g) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tilearray.size(); i++) {
            Tile t = (Tile) tilearray.get(i);
            g.drawImage(t.getTileImage(), t.getTileX(), t.getTileY(), this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            currentSprite = characterDown;
            if (robot.isJumped() == false) {
                robot.setDucked(true);
                robot.setSpeedX(0);
            }
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            robot.moveLeft();
            robot.setMovingLeft(true);
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            robot.moveRight();
            robot.setMovingRight(true);
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
            robot.jump();
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL:
            if (robot.isDucked() == false && robot.isJumped() == false
                    && robot.isReadyToFire()) {
                robot.shoot();
                robot.setReadyToFire(false);

            }
            break;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            currentSprite = anim.getImage();
            robot.setDucked(false);
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            robot.stopLeft();
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            robot.stopRight();
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL:
            robot.setReadyToFire(true);
            Sound.GUN.play();
            break;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public static Background getBg1() {
        return bg1;
    }

    public static Background getBg2() {
        return bg2;
    }

    public static Robot getRobot() {
        return robot;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getSource() == next) {
            level++;
        }

        if (evt.getSource() == sOver) {
            level = 1;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the Sound.java class that calls the sound files (Though I don't think it is needed for this particular question)

```
package androidGame;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;

public class Sound {
    public static final AudioClip MAIN = Applet.newAudioClip(Sound.class.getResource("soundtrack.au"));
    public static final AudioClip GUN = Applet.newAudioClip(Sound.class.getResource("gun.au"));
    public static final AudioClip DIE = Applet.newAudioClip(Sound.class.getResource("death.au"));
    public static final AudioClip WIN = Applet.newAudioClip(Sound.class.getResource("win.au"));
}
```

Comment: I don't see any question mark in the whole text, so... what is your question exactly ?

Comment: Can anyone see what in the code is causing the audio and button glitch on gamestate=Win and when you die of falling in a hole (robot.getCenterY() > 500)?

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing. 3) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: There are 9 total classes that come together to run this program. While I can post all of that code, it certainly does not meet the "minimal" aspect of an MCVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that the game was getting stuck in a loop on "win" or on "death by falling in a hole". Although I acknowledge it is not the most elegant of solutions, changing the code reflected below solves the problem.

```
                if (rHealth == 0) {
                    state = GameState.Dead;
                    Sound.MAIN.stop();
                    Sound.DIE.play();
                }

                if (robot.getCenterY() > 500) {
                    state = GameState.Dead;
                    robot.setCenterY(0);
                    robot.setCenterX(0);
                    Sound.MAIN.stop();
                    Sound.DIE.play();
                }

                if (score == 35) {
                    state = GameState.Win;
                    score = 40;
                    Sound.MAIN.stop();
                    Sound.WIN.play();
                }
            }
```